# Visual Studio 2013 - ASPX - Navigation Bar

Tags: web, visual-studio-2013, navigationbar

So one of our company left from one day to the other and he left me a really huge Webtool for Hardware/Software inventory. (It's like an AD/SCCM module, accessible by Web).

Now as it is really huge and I really have no idea of ASPX, webdev etc. I try to figure out what he did on my own.

He is building the different sites from a Master with a content placeholder (i guess) - but I cannot find the Navbar in the Master (in Designer view). (To be honest I checked every single file which seemed possible for me to host the navbar)

I need to remove one link out of the Nav-Bar but I really don't find where this s**t is defined here.

Is there a way to search the whole Project (all Files) for a specific wordset? (Which should be just on the button) or is it somewhere I didn't look at? I already checked Technet and co. but I don't see it inhere.

Could someone give me a hint where to check something like that?

I'm thankful for every little help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there could be a shared folder in the project that connectes the nav bar up to all pages. Or if you press ctrl + F (find) you can use the search feature for a word on the nav bar (there is a drop down to search through all projects/documents/etc).

EDIT:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ClientSideAPI.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="NavBar_ClientSideAPI" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHolder" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
```

Should be (sort of) what you're looking for.

Comment: You sir (@ElGavilan aswell) are both just great! Exactly what I was looking for and took 2 seconds to find!

Comment: btw. I gave the correct answer to you as you seem to be newer here, sorry ElGavilan!

Comment: thank you. @ElGavilan you've plenty of rep already it seems :P

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + SHIFT + F to bring up the find/replace dialog. Under "Look in:" you can choose to search the entire solution, current project, current document, or all currently open documents.